# how to only allow one domain to access files and folders in another domain

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, iframe

There are a set of folder in

/var/www/vhosts/abc/content.abc.com.au/httpdocs/ folder

Ex:

/var/www/vhosts/abc/content.abc.com.au/httpdocs/62199911-74c61aaf688c0d374f23253218a12a9b81eaba4c

/var/www/vhosts/abc/content.abc.com.au/httpdocs/62199911-74c61aaf688c0d374f23253218a12a9b81eab12d

I can access files in above folders using this url:

https://content.abc.com.au/62199911-74c61aaf688c0d374f23253218a12a9b81eaba4c/index.html
https://content.abc.com.au/62199911-74c61aaf688c0d374f23253218a12a9b81eab12d/index.html

I want to prevent direct access for those urls.

Then,

I have another php file in this(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/anothercontent.pqr.com.au) folder  named as "pdfview.php".

We can access the file using this url: https://abc.sample.com.au/pdfview.php
The "pdfview.php" file contain this iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://content.abc.com.au/62199911-74c61aaf688c0d374f23253218a12a9b81eab12d/index.html" allowfullscreen="" style="width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want to access below urls only through the iframe in "pdfview.php" page in this (https://abc.sample.com.au) domain, 
do not need to access in any other domain.
https://content.abc.com.au/62199911-74c61aaf688c0d374f23253218a12a9b81eaba4c/index.html
https://content.abc.com.au/62199911-74c61aaf688c0d374f23253218a12a9b81eab12d/index.html

I have tried to find a way to do this using htaccess file. but could not. is there a way to do that using htaccess or using php

Comment: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) and [php header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: @line88 there is no CORS AJAX request in play here, so Access-Control-Allow-Origin won’t do much. If anything, this is a case for an X-Frame-Options header.

Comment: @misorude The article at MDN is about headers and not just about AJAX CORS...let me quote for you `..A response that tells the browser to allow code from any origin to access a resource will include the following:...` + using php `header` will give expected result

Comment: @line88 “code” is the important word in what you quoted - this is about requests made via scripting code, so AJAX. A request caused by the mere presence of an iframe is not affected by this at all. _“will give expected result”_ - no, it won’t.

Answer (score -1):

How about modifying the .htaccess file.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 100.100.100.100
```

Comment: can you explain about the IP address 100.100.100.100 ?

Comment: When you have virtualhost

**<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/yourproject"
  ServerName yourproject.localhost
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/yourproject">
 Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from 100.100.100.100 (ip address of domain ) ( This one can only access the folder of project)
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>**

Comment: But it is not “the domain” making the request, it is my browser.